# While JAWS is running, Ctrl+f of browser does not work

Tags: internet-explorer, jaws-screen-reader

I am getting the issue while using global shortcuts in Internet Explorer.

When I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> in the browser, it should open browser’s find, but instead of that it opens JAWS find dialog.

How can I disable JAWS 'find' dialog on press of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you absolutely need to do this (I don't know what for, though), you can press **Insert+3** to pass the keystroke through to the application one time.
If you need to disable JAWS find permanently:

1. While in Internet Explorer, press **Insert+8** to go to the JAWS Keyboard manager.
2. You'll land in the list of applications. Press **Tab** to go to the list of scripts.
3. Locate *IEFind* which is the script name for Ctrl+F.
4. Press **Del** to remove the keystroke.
5. Confirm the removal, save your changes and exit Keyboard manager.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Menelion. 
It really works for me.
The reason why i need it because in my application in IE only when i was pressing Ctrl+F,it opens JAWS find dialog so i was not able to go to application search box.
I was surprised because that occurs only in IE browser.